# How to get row number of an array that's being looped through?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google AppScripts and found this script online which I've modified.

NOTE: Spreadsheet has headers.

1. Run through the values found in 3rd column
2. If any of the values include the word "USD", copy the entire row into "Target Sheet"
3. Delete that row after it's finished copying
4. Continuing looping through until it finds the next "USD"...etc.

**What Works:**
I'm successfully able to loop through the array and copy the correct rows into the "Target Sheet"

**What I Need Help With:**
I can't figure out how to delete the row from the original sheet. It always ends up deleting the row before, then skips 1 row every time it loops again. I've tried multiple different formats to this portion of the code, such as i-1, i+1, etc... Not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
if (i == 0) {
  ss1.deleteRow(i+2);
} else {
ss1.deleteRow(i)
}
```

I've pasted the entire script below:

```
var etfar = ["Cash File"] //This is a string because I have multiple sheets I'm looping through
 
function cashCopy(etf) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName(etf);
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet");
  var lr = ss1.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss1.getLastColumn();

// gets the data in Cash File
var range = ss1.getRange(1, 1, lr, lc);
var data = range.getValues();

// loops through rows in data
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var check = data[i][2] // ith row, 3rd column
  if (check.includes("USD")) { 

 var rowToCopy = data[i];
 ss2.appendRow(rowToCopy);
    
    if (i == 0) {
      ss1.deleteRow(i+2);
    } else {
    ss1.deleteRow(i)
                 }

  }; 
}; // end i
}

    for (var i = 0; i < etfar.length; i++) {
    cashCopy(etfar[i])
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

One way to iteratively delete rows in a sheet is to create a **backwards** `for` loop.

**Replace**:

`for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`

**with**:

`for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

In this way, every time you delete a row, the `data` will still correspond to the correct row.

---

Another issue is that you get `var range = ss1.getRange(1, 1, lr, lc)`. That means, you start iterating from the first row (including the headers) and then you are using a workaround like that:

```
if (i == 0) {
  ss1.deleteRow(i+2);
} else {
ss1.deleteRow(i)
             }
```

But actually, you don't need to include the headers in the first place. Use this instead: `var range = ss1.getRange(2, 1, lr, lc)` and replace the `if/else` statement with just: `ss1.deleteRow(i+2)`.

since `data` index starts from `0`, but your `range` starts from row `2`.

---

### Solution:

```
var etfar = ["Cash File"] //This is a string because I have multiple sheets I'm looping through
 
function cashCopy(etf) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName(etf);
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet");
  var lr = ss1.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss1.getLastColumn();

// gets the data in Cash File
var range = ss1.getRange(2, 1, lr, lc); // <- modification
var data = range.getValues();

// loops through rows in data
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
  var check = data[i][2] // ith row, 3rd column
  if (check.includes("USD")) { 

 var rowToCopy = data[i];
 ss2.appendRow(rowToCopy);
    
 ss1.deleteRow(i+2); // <- new code
    
  }; 
}; // end i
}

    for (var i = 0; i < etfar.length; i++) {
    cashCopy(etfar[i])
  }
```